Table and filter columns different in MUI Data Grid
In the Student Details column, I want to stack data values from three columns: Name, Major, and Year. Is it possible to do this while still maintaining the ability to filter by the individual columns? See image for an example where I want to filter by the Name and Major columns.
If not, is there another data grid library that would allow me to do this?


Yes, You can achieve this in MUI Datagrid. You can create a column which is hidden by default. But you can still filter rows by hidden columns. Check the steps below

Create a column with field: "year".

Hide the column in datagrid:
<DataGrid
    columnVisibilityModel={{ year: false,}}
    //other props
/>


Now if you open the filters, you will find this hidden column option in the list of filters.


